# Angular Test is not returning from task Azure Devops

Tags: angular, unit-testing, azure-devops

I am running unit test cases of Angular application through Azure pipeline. All these days it was working fine, From last week I am facing weird problem, even though my test cases are passing but the task in Azure devops pipeline is still running until eventually it gets time-out and the build pipeline eventually fails. I tried to run both the below tasks along with other ways to execute but for everything the tasks in the pipeline is stuck post successful execution of tests. in local it seems working fine, when I run headless it just executes and returns. Here are the task details

```
            - script: |
               cd '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Test-App'
               npm install -g @angular/cli
               ng test --browsers=Chrome_Max
              displayName: 'test app'
```

other one is

```
      - task: Npm@1
        inputs:
          command: 'custom'
          workingDir: 'Test-App'
          customCommand: 'run test-headless-coverage'
```

headless coverage is

> ng test --browsers=Chrome_Max --code-coverage

and chrome max is custom settings to get into the full screen mode

```
 customLaunchers: {
      Chrome_Max: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: ['--window-size=1600,800'],
      },
    },
```

I tried to run without customization, plain ng test, there also its the same issue. any idea what settings do I have to tweak?

Comment: I am not sure why it was working before but I suspect it could be because of the `watch` flag being on now meaning the test never exits and it waiting for changes to files so it can re-run the tests. Of course, you don't want this feature in `CI` pipeline. Could you try running with watch false `ng test --browsers=Chrome_Max --watch=false`?

Comment: thanks, that settings was already in place but like this --watch false instead of --watch=false

Comment: Check what this article adds to the `karma.conf.js`: https://purple.telstra.com/blog/run-angular-unit-tests-in-gitlab-ci. I think you need to do something similar if you're running the unit tests in Azure Devops in a Linux/Docker environment.